# Is merge sort is external or internal?

Tags: sorting, data-structures

Actually sorting techniques are two types according to memory usage. One is that internal Another one is that external.

Insertion selection exchange sorts are internal sorts. That means they are processed in internal memory.

But I don't know about merge sort?

Comment: [Both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Variants)?

Comment: Random access is relatively slow on most external devices, so almost all external sorts are variations of merge sort. The initial phase reads "chunks" of data into memory, does an internal sort (any reasonably fast sort will work for the internal sort), then writes the sorted "chunks" of data to external device(s). After that, the sorted "chunks" of data are repeatedly merged until a single sorted run of data is created.

Comment: @rcgldr - "repeatedly merged" is not typically how a merge is done. Rather, all chunks are merged in a single pass. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm#Direct_k-way_merge. That requires a lot less I/O than repeated merges.

Comment: @JimMischel - I meant repeatedly merged when there are more than k chunks being merged using a k-way merge. Gnu sort does this, using a 16 way merge to merge what could be more than 16 temp files. It detects when it's reached the final merge that will produce a single file, and uses the user specified output file name for that final merged file (prior to that, it's using temp file names).

Comment: @rcgldr I didn't know that about Gnu `sort`. I wonder why it limits k to 16 chunks. Might have to track that one down. Seems like you'd want as many chunks as you can possibly get at once, to reduce I/O.

Comment: @JimMischel - one issue could be the amount of memory available versus "k". A higher value for "k" means a smaller buffer for each I/O, increasing the relative overhead of random access. Another potential issue is the process might become cpu bound instead of I/O bound for "k" much larger than 16. It could also be a legacy issue, when systems had less memory than they do today.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write a completely internal merge sort. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ for an example.

People often talk about an "external merge sort", but that often works out to a two-pass sorting technique where you successively load small portions of a large file into memory, sort them, and write them to disk. In the second pass, you merge those multiple portions into a single sorted file. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting for details.